# Setting up replication on MySQL, MySQL won't start

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have setup replication previously and all went smoothly. I am trying on a new server to setup replication and when enabling the log-bin variable in my my.cnf MySQL will not start up. I read somewhere that during execution MySQL does a chdir and this causes issues with it not being able to find the log files but I can't see how that is the case.

When I uncomment the following two lines in my my.cnf file:

```
#log-bin=/var/log/mysql/replication_logs/mysql-bin.log
#binlog-do-db=database_name
```

I receive the following error from mysqld,

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/replication_logs/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
120321 20:55:09 [ERROR] Aborting
```

By listing out the directory where the logs are,

```
root@server:/var/log/mysql/replication_logs# ls -alh
total 8.0K
drwxr-sr-x 2 mysql adm 4.0K 2012-03-14 21:41 .
drwxr-s--- 3 mysql adm 4.0K 2012-03-21 06:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql adm    0 2012-03-14 21:41 mysql-bin.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql adm    0 2012-03-14 20:35 mysql-bin-index.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql adm    0 2012-03-14 20:35 mysql-bin.log
```

The permissions are the same as the error.log permissions. The versions of MySQL I am running is,

Server version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 (Ubuntu)

If you have any advice or tips it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I took out the full path and just left a relative file name and it works.